# Slicing a list and group

Tags: python, list

For example, if our source list is:

```
input = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, ... ]
```

And I need something like this:

```
output = {1:[1], 2:[2,3], 3:[4,5,6], 4:[7,8,9,...], ...}
```

I try like this, but this not work correctly:

```
groups = {}
N = 1
group = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
for i in range(0, len(group)-1):
    groups.update({N:group[i:i+N]})
    N+=1
```

Comment: Don't name your variable `input` as it shadows the builtin

Comment: This only for example

Comment: where should it end?

Comment: This seems like a fun problem. I say we benchmark all the solutions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is almost right but the logic is off. I added a variable called `start` that is the index at which each new group should start, and changed the loop into a `while`; when the `start` is greater or equal to the length of the list, we have processed all items.

```
groups = {}
N = 1
group = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
start = 0
while start < len(group):
    groups[N] = group[start:start + N]
    start += N
    N += 1
```

Output

```
{1: [1], 2: [2, 3], 3: [4, 5, 6], 4: [7, 8, 9, 10]}
```

Also, there is no need to use update, a simple assign to a dictionary key will do fine here.

Answer (score 5):

For completeness sake - you can also write a version which will work on any iterable:

```
from itertools import islice, count

group = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
res = {k:v for k,v in enumerate(iter(lambda i=iter(group), c=count(1): list(islice(i, next(c))), []), 1)}
# {1: [1], 2: [2, 3], 3: [4, 5, 6], 4: [7, 8, 9, 10]}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use one dict comprehension but first you need to find a proper index range that you could split your elements based on them! for this aim you can use a simple mathematical formula that the sum of a sequence from 1...n is `n*(n+1)/2` so in this case `n*(n+1)/2=len(l)` and with solving the equation you can achieve the `n` with `(1+math.sqrt(1+8*len(l)))/2)` :

Some examples :

```
>>> l=[23,12,33,42,5,6,7,8,39,10,11,102]
>>> ind=range(1,int((1+math.sqrt(1+8*len(l)))/2))
>>> {i:l[sum(ind[:i-1]):sum(ind[:i-1])+i] for i in ind}
{1: [23], 2: [12, 33], 3: [42, 5, 6], 4: [7, 8, 39, 10]}
```

As the length of `11,102` is not 5 so the n will be 4 in this case! but in following it covers all the elements :

```
>>> l=[23,12,33,42,5,6,7,8,39,10,11,102,4,0,5]
>>> ind=range(1,int((1+math.sqrt(1+8*len(l)))/2))
>>> {i:l[sum(ind[:i-1]):sum(ind[:i-1])+i] for i in ind}
{1: [23], 2: [12, 33], 3: [42, 5, 6], 4: [7, 8, 39, 10], 5: [11, 102, 4, 0, 5]}
```

And as a better way you can just calculate the `sum(ind[:i-1])` one time :

```
>>> for i in ind:
...    s=sum(ind[:i-1])
...    d[i]=l[s:s+i]
... 
>>> d
{1: [23], 2: [12, 33], 3: [42, 5, 6], 4: [7, 8, 39, 10], 5: [11, 102, 4, 0, 5]}
```

*Last Note* as you can see in first example this solution doesn't keep the last elements if their number doesn't match with the corresponding length. if you want to keep the last elements You can use other answers that are good stuffs!

Comment: Quadratic formula and triangular numbers? Impressive :) I was thinking of something similar.

Comment: What about `l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,11]`?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham `{1: [1], 2: [2, 3], 3: [4, 5, 6], 4: [7, 8, 9, 10]}
`

Comment: @Those confused, This is solved by using the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation and n(n+1)/2 formula used comes from here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number

Comment: Are we not supposed to keep 11?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham OP doesn't clarify that but i was thinking about adding an alternative for that!

Answer (score 3):

Similar to Jon's approach:

```
from itertools import islice 
it = iter(l)      
d = {k: v for k,v in ((i,list(islice(it, i))) for i in range(1, len(l))) if v}
print(d)
{1: [1], 2: [2, 3], 3: [4, 5, 6], 4: [7, 8, 9, 10]}
```

Or using takewhile and itemgetter:

```
from itertools import islice,takewhile
from operator import itemgetter

it = iter(l)

d = {k: v for k,v in takewhile(itemgetter(1),((i,list(islice(it, i))) for i in range(1, len(l))))}
print(d)
{1: [1], 2: [2, 3], 3: [4, 5, 6], 4: [7, 8, 9, 10]}
```

The takewhile is a lot more efficient:

```
In [18]: l = list(range(100000))

In [19]: %%timeit
it = iter(l)
d = {k: v for k,v in takewhile(itemgetter(1),((i,list(islice(it, i))) for i in range(1, len(l))))}
   ....: 
100 loops, best of 3: 2.51 ms per loop    
In [20]: %%timeit
it = iter(l)                 
d = {k: v for k,v in ((i,list(islice(it, i))) for i in range(1, len(l))) if v}
   ....: 
10 loops, best of 3: 65.7 ms per loop
In [29]: timeit {k:v for k,v in enumerate(iter(lambda i=iter(group), c=count(1): list(islice(i, next(c))), []), 1)}
100 loops, best of 3: 2.74 ms per loop

In [33]: %%timeit
  ....: it = iter(l)
  ....: dict(zip(count(1), takewhile(lambda x: x, (list(islice(it, i))   for i in count(1)))))
   ....: 
   100 loops, best of 3: 2.73 ms per loop
```

Well math wins but not by as much as I thought:

```
In [23]: timeit  dict(groups(l))

1000 loops, best of 3: 1.53 ms per loop
```

Using `itertools.count` in place of range knocks a little more off:

```
n [36]: %%timeit
   ....: it = iter(l)
   ....: {k: v for k, v in takewhile(itemgetter(1),
   ....:         ((i, list(islice(it, i))) for i in count(1)))}
   ....: 
100 loops, best of 3: 2.38 ms per loop
```

For a more concise option use dict:

```
it = iter(l)
d= dict(takewhile(itemgetter(1),
    ((i, list(islice(it, i))) for i in count(1))))
```

Comment: That looks better! :)

Comment: @BhargavRao, happy now Professor Bhargav ? ;)

Comment: Slower by 6 secs ... That is bad

Comment: @BhargavRao, I am getting old, s**t happens ;)

Comment: Nice solution! :) And yeah math will pretty much always win unless you're comparing math to a high-speed-access cache of pre-computed solutions.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Can you test also mine? `dict(izip(count(1), takewhile(lambda x: x, (list(islice(it, i)) for i in count(1)))))`

Comment: @JuniorCompressor, sure, I changed to using zip as I did all the testing on python3 due to the use of range

Answer (score 2):

A math-based solution:

```
import math

def groups(l):
  for i in range(1,int((math.sqrt(8*len(l)+1)+1)/2)):
    start = int(i*(i-1)/2)
    yield i, l[start:start+i]

l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
r = dict(groups(l))
```

Result: `r == {1: [1], 2: [2, 3], 3: [4, 5, 6], 4: [7, 8, 9, 10]}`

Version that doesn't truncate:

```
import math

def groups(l):
  for i in range(1,math.ceil((math.sqrt(8*len(l)+1)+1)/2)):
    start = int(i*(i-1)/2)
    yield i, l[start:min(start+i,len(l))]

l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
r = dict(groups(l))
```

Result: `r == {1: [1], 2: [2, 3], 3: [4, 5, 6], 4: [7, 8, 9, 10], 5: [11]}`

Comment: You would lose `11` if you add it

Comment: True, but adding `11` through `15` does work. The question doesn't specify whether the input may not fit the output format.

Comment: Yes, just pointing out that it truncates, I asked the OP where it should end in a comment.

Comment: added a non-truncating version

Comment: well plus1, I was trying  math approach first but got the formula wrong. Will have to time them and see

Answer (score 1):

You can use a generator:

```
from itertools import count, repeat

def gen(it):
    for i in count(1):
        yield i, map(next, repeat(it, i))

print dict(gen(iter([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])))
```

Result:

```
{1: [1], 2: [2, 3], 3: [4, 5, 6], 4: [7, 8, 9, 10]}
```

Or just:

```
from itertools import count, takewhile, islice, izip

it = iter([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
dict(izip(count(1), takewhile(lambda x: x, (list(islice(it, i)) for i in count(1)))))
```